# PyCharm: Debug Javascript in Django Template

Tags: javascript, django, debugging, pycharm

I cannot figure out how to debug javascript, using PyCharm, in a Django template.

When I attempt to debug a template -- by using the context menu item Debug while in the template -- the debugger launches, chromium launches, and I see the following error message in the PyCharm debugger console:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Needless to say nothing shows up in the chromium window.

I've seen hints that I'm supposed to "open the generated file" from within the PyCharm debugger scripts tab. But since chromium isn't loading anything there's nothing to open.

I have the JetBrains chromium debugger installed and, so far as I can tell, running.

What's the procedure for debugging javascript in a Django template from within PyCharm?

Comment: use browser for that

Comment: not sure what you mean. Use the browser's javascript debugger?

Answer (score 3):

Set up a debug configuration for Javascript (not Remote Firefox/Remote Chrome as the documentation might lead you to). Set the URL to the entrypoint of your application that renders the template and run this config. It should launch a browser and stop at any breakpoints you set in your javascript in pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a browser tool like firebug in browser or google chome debugging tools (depending on the browser you use), If your code is client side, since I assume that the server side part of the application is written in python scripts it's the easiest solution.
I have also used JSDT in eclipse but it was not as convenient.

For the error you posted I think it's server-side / networks error, check your views.py or an example from the django tutorial to see if it is exposed in WSGI (django default web server ).

Comment: If he asks for this (and I'm in the same case) it's because it's much more easy and practical to debug in the same editor and variable inspections in PyCharm are much more powerful than what you can find in both firebug or google chome debugging tools.

Comment: Sure for a simple js script it is possible. The runtime in the browser is a tricky thing JS most of the time interacts with HTML and css and other code that you may not have in before the browser all the external scripts (coming from cnd or other sources). 

So again it may work with smaller webapps but in complex web apps I would advice against that (IMHO).